# Country codes and dial codes ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Im doing a little project which involves

- country list
- country abbreviation list e.g UK, US.
- dial code.

if a user enters +44, it should pull the country and country abbreviation

I was wondering what the best way to implement this is? shall i create 3 different hashes? or use nested hashes?

Comment: Depends on how many ways you need to access the data. Is the input always the dialing code, or do you sometimes need to take a country code and get the dialing code, or take a country name and get the dial code, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before reinventing the wheel, you should check existing solutions like the [countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries):

```
c.number #=> "840"
c.alpha2 #=> "US"
c.alpha3 #=> "USA"
c.country_code #=> "1"
c.national_destination_code_lengths #=> 3
c.national_number_lengths #=> 10
c.international_prefix #=> "011"
c.national_prefix #=> "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking because you need to be able to look up your data based on any of the fields, you could map your records to three different hashes using something like the following, where each hash is indexed by the relevant field.

```
country_codes, names, dial_codes = [
  { country_code: "GB", name: "United Kingdom", dial_code: "44" },
  { country_code: "AU", name: "Australia",      dial_code: "61" },
  { country_code: "IT", name: "Italy",          dial_code: "39" }
].inject([{}, {}, {}]) do |(cc, n, dc), record|
  [
    cc.merge(record[:country_code] => record),
    n.merge(record[:name]         => record),
    dc.merge(record[:dial_code]    => record)
  ]
end

p country_codes["AU"]
# => { country_code: "AU", name: "Australia", dial_code: "61" }

p dial_codes["44"]
# => { country_code: "GB", name: "United Kingdom", dial_code: "44" }
```

Also note that the official country code for the UK is GB, not UK.  Confusing, I know.

Comment: "official country code for the UK is GB" . . . That's probably because the UK is legally a country that consists of several countries. That kind of reality often confuses committees.